# acts as taggable with merb?

Tags: ruby, merb

Is there a acts as taggable solution out there for merb users already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dm-tags](http://dm-tags.rubyforge.org/) for Datamapper.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the answer to your question as asked is "No".

I did find [this](http://www.mbleigh.com/2008/6/11/gemplugins-a-brief-introduction-to-the-future-of-rails-plugins) which at least shows some interest, but it's a few months old now with no apparent progress.

Maybe you could get some more information by rephrasing the question? Something like "what options are available for tagging in Merb?"